# ChartJS does not render correctly

Tags: chart.js

I'm having problems using ChartJS.
It renders the chart perfectly but for some reason, with certain parameters it renders in an odd way.
Would anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

[image: Wrong Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your data is in the incorrect way in the data array. Try sorting your array first and then put it in chartjs to chart it